# In clojure how do I require a multimethod?

Tags: clojure

I know I can do `(:use function)` but how do I do this for a multimethod?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multimethods are used from other namespaces in the same way as functions.

If you have the following in com/example/foo.clj

```
(ns com.example.foo)

(defn f [x]
  (* x x))

(defmulti m first)

(defmethod m :a [coll]
  (map inc (rest coll)))
```

In the file com/example/bar.clj you can use both f and m in the same manner:

```
(ns com.example.bar
  (:use [com.example.foo :only [f m]]))

(defn g []
  (println (f 5)) ; Call the function
  (println (m [:a 1 2 3]))) ; Call the multimethod

;; You can also define new cases for the multimethod defined in foo
;; which are then available everywhere m is
(defmethod m :b [coll]
  (map dec (rest coll)))
```

I hope this answers your question!